# How do I work in creating education standards?

Tags: secondary-education, curriculum

I'm interested in playing a role in determining mathematics curriculum and goals for K-12 students. I'm currently a college student. How do I even begin down this path? Math? Political Science? Education?

Comment: Standard for which country? Or, if the U.S., which state?

Comment: First you should get many years experience teaching K-12 math.   In the past, standards promulgated by others (such as politicians, or university math professors) have sometimes been  impractical.

Comment: (U.S. based comment) This is an extremely hard, possible unanswerable question.

Comment: In the US, there are three career tracks you can have. Track 1: become an expert in math and math education, propose reasonable standards, and have them ignored by politicians. Track 2: become a politician at the higher levels of political power, make up totally unrealistic standards, impose them on educators by fiat, watch them fail. Track 3: become a politician at the lower levels of political power, note that you are about to get in trouble because students are failing the standards, water down the standards until a state of political equilibrium is reached.

Comment: @BenCrowell Isn't it a bit early in the new year to systematically squash the hopes and ambitions of our youth?

Ninjawartotles:  Keep up the good fight.  I would say that Ben's Track 1 is the noblest path, but that change is possible.

Comment: @StevenGubkin: If OP is going to find some way of cutting this Gordian Knot, he first needs to know of its existence (for, like, the last century or so).

Comment: Whan I read your question, my first reaction was "What is K-12?", and that's maybe a first start for you: how can you play a role in K-12 (in anything in fact) if you don't know where it's different than others? Do you know other systems than K-12, and do you know how to list the differences, advantages, disadvantes, ...? Just by writing this down, you might get an idea of the regions where extra effort might be interesting.

Answer (score 4):

As somebody who has been involved in state and national standards work, I think there are a few ways in.  **Most important, become a mathematics teacher and gain some experience in your public schools**.  From here, you will have opportunities to engage in larger conversations around district and state policies and figure out who's who in that world.

Seek out opportunities to be around the people in your district who are a part of these conversations, gain experience, and eventually there will be district level positions or state positions around curriculum and instruction.

Along the way, you should complete higher degrees, specifically studying mathematics education.

There is no quick road, fortunately, and you should expect years of classroom teaching before considering a seat at the table. This is only fair.